# How to create access keys that only have access to specific S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have four S3 buckets `bucket1, bucket2, bucket3, bucket4`. I would like to create a new Access/secret key that only has access to these four buckets.

How should I do this? Should I use IAM to create a new user, then login as that user, and create the S3 buckets? Would I need to create a new policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an IAM policy that only gives access to these four buckets. You do this by specifying the ARN of each bucket in the policy. Create an IAM user and assign the policy to that user. Create access keys for that user.

[Here is some documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) on creating the IAM policy to grant access to specific S3 buckets.

Comment: While creating a role, what should be selected for "Select Role Type" (step 2) screen? I expected to see AWS S3 there but I do not.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you an incorrect bit of info. Don't create a role. Just create the policy and attach it directly to the user.